# elasticsearch xpack - Can’t change default password

Tags: elasticsearch

I installed Xpack for elasticsearch, and tried to to change the password as it says here:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/x-pack/current/security-getting-started.html

Running this:

```
curl -XPUT -u elastic localhost:9200/_xpack/security/user/elastic/_password -H Content-Type: application/json -d {"password" : "elasticpassword"}
```

is getting me:

> ```
> {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"json_parse_exception","reason":"Unexpected character ('p' (code 112)): was expecting double-quote to start field name\n
> at [Source: org.elasticsearch.transport.netty4.ByteBufStreamInput@4a142671; line: 1, column: 3]"}],"type":"json_parse_exception","reason":"Unexpected character ('p' (code 112)): was expecting double-quote to start field name\n 
> at [Source: org.elasticsearch.transport.netty4.ByteBufStreamInput@4a142671; line: 1, column: 3]"},"status":500}curl: (6) Could not resolve host: application
> curl: (3) Bad URL, colon is first character
> curl: (3) [globbing] unmatched close brace/bracket in column 16
> ```

or, running this:

```
curl -XPUT -u elastic "localhost:9200/_xpack/security/user/elastic/_password" -H "Content-Type: application/json -d {"password" : "elasticpassword"}
```

gets me this:

> ```
> {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"not_x_content_exception","reason":"Compressor detection can only be called on some xcontent bytes or compressed xcontent bytes"}],"type":"not_x_content_exception","reason":"Compressor detection can only be called on some xcontent bytes or compressed xcontent bytes"},"status":500}
> ```

I can't seem to get it, no matter what combination of " or ' I'm using. Please help!

Thanks

Comment: Are you using windows cmd?

Comment: Try this : `curl -XPUT -u elastic localhost:9200/_xpack/security/user/elastic/_password -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{\"password\" : \"elasticpassword\"}"`

Comment: Damn! It worked! Thank you so much!

Comment: Could I add the response? Because I want to relate some links I guess this is a general problem of windows users.

Comment: https://discuss.elastic.co/t/index-a-new-document/35281/8 same discussion and response.

Comment: Of course. I'll mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is general problem of Windows users. You can use [Sense](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/sense/current/index.html) Chrome Plugin or Kibana Dev Tools instead.

```
curl -XPUT -u elastic localhost:9200/_xpack/security/user/elastic/_password -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{\"password\" : \"elasticpassword\"}"
```

Please check the elastic developer response about this situation:
https://discuss.elastic.co/t/index-a-new-document/35281/8